# Tabbed Panels in asp & Dreamweaver

Tags: asp-classic, dreamweaver, tabbed

Is the any way one can have the tabinxex or tabid shown in the link bar on every click?

Eg: http://link.co.za/MaintenanceProfile.asp?MaintenanceID=154&ClientID=32&Tab=4

Comment: Huh? Further information required.

Comment: When clicked on one of the tabs in Spray Tabbed Panels, i would like to have the tabID display in the url parameter. So when you click on the first tab url will be: http://link.co.za/MaintenanceProfile.asp?MaintenanceID=154&ClientID=32&Tab=0

Comment: second tab wil be: http://link.co.za/MaintenanceProfile.asp?MaintenanceID=154&ClientID=32&Tab=2

Comment: the aim of the exercise is, when page refreshes it maintains selected tab and do not return to default, 0

Comment: the bottom of my page looks like this:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1");
//-->
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1", {defaultTab:<%= Request.QueryString("Tab") %>});
//-->
</script>